# Is it possible to extend Celery, so results would be store to several MongoDB collections?

Tags: mongodb, celery

I've started a new project and I want to make Celery save results to several MongoDB collections instead of one. Is there a way to do that through configs or do I need to extend Celery and Kombu to achieve that?

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm not really interesting in knowing weather I can extend Celery, but I'm more interested in ways to extend it, that would meet the requirement of saving task result to different MongoDB collections

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to modify Celery, you can extend it. That's exactly what I did for one internal project. I didn't want to touch the standard results backend (Redis in my case), but wanted to also store the tasks' state and results in MongoDB for good while enhancing the state/results at the same time.

I ended up creating a little library with class called `TaskTracker` that uses [Celery signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) machinery to achieve the goal. The key parts of the implementation look like this:

```
import datetime

from celery import signals, states
from celery.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from pymongo import MongoClient, ReturnDocument

class TaskTracker(object):
    """Track task processing and store the state in MongoDB."""

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.config = app.conf.get('task_tracker')
        if not self.config:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Task tracker configuration missing')
        self.tasks = set()
        self._mongo = None

        self._connect_signals()

    @property
    def mongo(self):
        # create client on first use to avoid 'MongoClient opened before fork.'
        # warning
        if not self._mongo:
            self._mongo = self._connect_to_mongodb()
        return self._mongo

    def _connect_to_mongodb(self):
        client = MongoClient(self.config['mongodb']['uri'])
        # check connection / error handling
        # ...
        return client

    def _connect_signals(self):
        signals.task_received.connect(self._on_task_received)
        signals.task_prerun.connect(self._on_task_prerun)
        signals.task_retry.connect(self._on_task_retry)
        signals.task_revoked.connect(self._on_task_revoked)
        signals.task_success.connect(self._on_task_success)
        signals.task_failure.connect(self._on_task_failure)

    def _on_task_received(self, sender, request, **other_kwargs):
        if request.name not in self.tasks:
            return

        collection = self.mongo \
            .get_database(self.config['mongodb']['database']) \
            .get_collection(self.config['mongodb']['collection'])
        collection.find_one_and_update(
            {'_id': request.id},
            {
                '$setOnInsert': {
                    'name': request.name,
                    'args': request.args,
                    'kwargs': request.kwargs,
                    'date_received': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                    'job_id': request.message.headers.get('job_id')
                },
                '$set': {
                    'status': states.RECEIVED,
                    'root_id': request.root_id,
                    'parent_id': request.parent_id
                },
                '$push': {
                    'status_history': {
                        'date': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                        'status': states.RECEIVED
                    }
                }
            },
            upsert=True,
            return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)

    # similarly for other signals...
    def _on_task_prerun(self, sender, task_id, task, args, kwargs,
                        **other_kwargs):
        # ...

    def _on_task_retry(self, sender, request, reason, einfo, **other_kwargs):
        # ...

    # ...

    def track(self, task):
        """Set up tracking for given task."""
        # accept either task name or task instance (for use as a decorator)
        if isinstance(task, str):
            self.tasks.add(task)
        else:
            self.tasks.add(task.name)
            return task
```

Then you need to provide configuration for MongoDB. I use YAML configuration file for Celery so it looks like this:

```
# standard Celery settings...
# ...

task_tracker:
    # MongoDB database for storing task state and results
    mongodb:
        uri: "\
            mongodb://myuser:mypassword@\
            mymongo.mydomain.com:27017/?\
            replicaSet=myreplica&tls=true&connectTimeoutMS=5000&\
            w=1&wtimeoutMS=3000&readPreference=primaryPreferred&maxStalenessSeconds=-1&\
            authSource=mydatabase&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
        database: 'mydatabase'
        collection: 'tasks'
```

In your tasks module, you just create the class instance providing your Celery app and decorate your tasks:

```
import os

from celery import Celery
import yaml

from celery_common.tracking import TaskTracker  # my custom utils library


config_file = os.environ.get('CONFIG_FILE', default='/srv/celery/config.yaml')
with open(config_file) as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f) or {}

app = Celery(__name__)
app.conf.update(config)

tracker = TaskTracker(app)

@tracker.track
@app.task(name='mytask')
def mytask(myparam1, myparam2, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Now your tasks' state and results are going to be tracked in MongoDB, separate from the standard results backend. If you need to store it in multiple databases, you can adjust it a bit, create multiple `TaskTracker` instances and provide multiple decorators to your tasks.

Comment: I think every serious Celery user at some point implemented own monitoring using the Monitoring and Inspection APIs... Me included.

Comment: Agreed. The primary reason for my solution was a bit different, though. I wanted to provide general job management functionality for our users and Celery (plus RedBeat as a scheduler) is just the execution part, runtime for jobs. MongoDB then serves as a permanent storage for information about job runs.

Answer (score 0):

Celery is licensed under The BSD License. The source code is on https://github.com/celery/celery

> it is possible to extend Celery ?

Yes, of course. This is parts of the freedom granted by [open source](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source) licenses.

> I was wondering weather I can make Celery and save results to several MongoDB collections instead of one?

So you download the source code and take the necessary time and efforts to study it and modify it.

Read about [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) a software development. Consider proposing your code improvements upstream (on [github](https://github.com/), with a pull request).

Comment: I already done the forking part, though it seems that I will need to extend kombu library too. Before I dive deeper I decided to ask maybe there is an easier way, without implementing changes to several libraries